# Add library to gradle build

Tags: java, dependencies, gradle

I'm trying to add `org.apache.commons.lang3` to my build. I've downloaded the library which is directory containing jar files.

My group is using gradle to build the project, and I know just enough to maybe ask the right question. So what I think the build is doing is

1. copying a bunch of .bnds to the build directory
2. compiles the java we have in src/main/java (via source sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs?)

I would like to add the lang3 library, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Can I just dump it into src/main/java? Or do I have to tell gradle about it?

This is what I think is relevant from the current build.gradle

```
ext.releaseDir = "${buildDir}/release/${tpVersion.getProgramName()}"
ext.bundlesDir = "${releaseDir}/nucleus/bin/nucleus_java/bundles/"

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: bundlesDir, include: '*.jar')

bnd {
   source sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
   include '**/*.bnd'
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It turns out we do use Maven, but I don't know enough about how all this works, so maybe my question was lacking. One of the code guys was able to add in the library today.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could declare it as a dependency, if it exists in any remote repository. That's the way I would do it.

But if you want to use the local file, do not put it in src/main. Use an extra folder called lib or similar on the same directory level as src or you build script.

Then you can add the local dependency to the build.gradle as in this sample:

```
repositories {
    //central maven repo
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //local file
    compile files('libs/toxiclibscore.jar')

    //dependencies from a remote repository
    compile 'java3d:vecmath:1.3.1', 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
}
```

Comment: As 'compile' is deprecated from Android 3.+, what should we use instead of compile?

Comment: @AanalMehta `compile` was replaced by `implementation`

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way is to use maven repository for accessing dependencies.

You can also access this jar directly from filesystem with [file dependencies](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#file-dependencies).

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/a.jar', 'libs/b.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Comment: The `compile` keyword has been deprecated. One of the alternatives might be `implementation`.