# Import Android project into a Flutter package

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I am developing a Flutter app that uses my own fork of a Flutter package called `vocsy_epub_viewer` (https://github.com/vongrad/vocsy_epub_viewer) as I need to make some changes in it.

I have included the plugin in `pubspec.yaml` and this part is working well:

```
dev_dependencies:
  vocsy_epub_viewer:
    path: dependencies/vocsy_epub_viewer
```

The `vocsy_epub_viewer` package contains a Flutter plugin acting as a bridge to call some platform specific code - for Android it is using `vocsy_epub_viewer_android_folioreader`. I have made a fork of this Android package as well (https://github.com/vongrad/vocsy_epub_viewer_android_folioreader) since I need to make changes in it.

In the Flutter package's `dependencies/vocsy_epub_viewer/android/build.gradle` file, the Android package was referenced as:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.kaushikgodhani:vocsy_epub_viewer_android_folioreader:V3'
}
```

I however need to make it such that it is referenced from a local folder where it was cloned (`./vocsy_epub_viewer_android_folioreader`).

The project structure looks as following:

```
flutter project root
    dependencies
        vocsy_epub_viewer
            android
                settings.gradle
                build.gradle
                
    android
        settings.gradle
        build.gradle
    ios
    lib
    ...
    
vocsy_epub_viewer_android_folioreader  <--- this plugin needs to be included within vocsy_epub_viewer/android
    folioreader
        settings.gradle
        build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    build.gradle
```

I have tried to include it as following:

dependencies/vocsy_epub_viewer/android/settings.gradle

```
include ':folioreader'
project(':folioreader').projectDir = file('C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\Projects\\vocsy_epub_viewer_android_folioreader')
```

dependencies/vocsy_epub_viewer/android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.folioreader:folioreader" <-- attempt to import the package from a local folder
    // implementation 'com.github.kaushikgodhani:vocsy_epub_viewer_android_folioreader:V3' <-- original import
}
```

But it does not seem to work. I would greatly appreciate if I could get an advice as of how to do this.

**EDIT**:
I have also tried changing the `dependencies/vocsy_epub_viewer/android/build.gradle` as suggested by @Sajjad to:

```
implementation project(':folioreader')
```

but got the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\test\Documents\Projects\waily\dependencies\vocsy_epub_viewer\android\build.gradle' line: 40

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':vocsy_epub_viewer'.
> Project with path ':folioreader' could not be found in project ':vocsy_epub_viewer'.
```

Comment: I hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21038488/10147641

Comment: new suggestion :) change  `file('C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\Projects\\vocsy_epub_viewer_android_folioreader')`
**with**
`file('C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\Projects\\vocsy_epub_viewer_android_folioreader\\folioreader')`

Comment: I have tried that and it produced the same error as in the `edit`

Answer (score 1):

please check this way.

reference your custom `vocsy_epub_viewer_android_folioreader` from https://jitpack.io

---

step 1 : Add it in your `flutterRoot > vocsy_epub_viewer > android >` build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Step 2. Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.vongrad:vocsy_epub_viewer_android_folioreader:master-SNAPSHOT'
    }
```

---

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Is there any way that it would not be referenced from a remote git repo but from a local directory? The reason for it is that I do not want that I need to commit my changes to a git repo during development in order to be able to test it in the Flutter app.

Comment: @Adam, so I think you have done 99% of Task, please try below link and say us what is the error , https://stackoverflow.com/a/46100715/6813907

Comment: @Adam For Example, I guess `implementation "com.folioreader:folioreader"` should change with `compile project(path:  ': folioreader')`

Comment: And may be this syntax works `implementation project(': folioreader')` from original Doc https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:project_dependencies

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have tried to apply your changes but without any success. Please see the updated question.